# ¿Cuál es mi error en este código?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Cómo les va? Les dejo mi pequeño problemita.
Para ponerlos en contexto, el problema me pide que el usuario ingrese sus datos, nombre, apellido, edad, dirección y teléfono (fijo y movil) donde éste último dato es opcional. Además, me dice que tengo una clase llamada Persona donde en ella habrá una estructura llamada Dato que a su vez tendrá una estructura anidada llamada Telefono.También me dice que tengo que usar constructores de clase y de estructura. Les dejo una screenshot del problema y el código. Desde ya, muchas gracias.
[image: El problema]

```
    class Persona {
      public:
             string nombreApellido, edad, direccion;

      struct Dato{

             struct Telefono{
                    string fijo, movil;

             Telefono (string fijo, string movil){
                    this->fijo=fijo;
                    this->movil=movil;
             }

             Telefono(string fijo){
                    this->fijo=fijo;
                    movil="NULL";
             }

             Telefono (string movil){
                    this->movil=movil;
                    fijo="NULL";
             }

             Telefono(){
                    fijo="NULL";
                    movil="NULL";
             }

             };

             Dato (string fijo, string movil){
                  tele=Telefono(fijo, movil);
             }

             Dato(string fijo){
                         tele=Telefono(fijo);
             }

             Dato (string movil){
                  tele=Telefono(movil);
             }

             Dato(){
                    tele=Telefono();
             }

             Telefono tele;
      };

      Persona (){}
      Persona (string nombreApellido, string edad, string direccion, string fijo, string movil){
              this->nombreApellido=nombreApellido;
              this->edad=edad;
              this->direccion=direccion;
              da=Dato(fijo, movil);
      }

      Persona (string nombreApellido, string edad, string direccion, string fijo){
              this->nombreApellido=nombreApellido;
              this->edad=edad;
              this->direccion=direccion;
              da=Dato(fijo);
      }

      Persona (string nombreApellido, string edad, string direccion, string movil){
              this->nombreApellido=nombreApellido;
              this->edad=edad;
              this->direccion=direccion;
              da=Dato(movil);
      }

      Persona (string nombreApellido, string edad, string direccion){
              this->nombreApellido=nombreApellido;
              this->edad=edad;
              this->direccion=direccion;
              da=Dato();
      }

      void Ingreso()
      {
           Persona pero[5];
           string nombreApellido, edad, direccion, fijo, movil;
           for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
           {
               cout<<"Ingrese el nombre y apellido: ";
               getline(cin,nombreApellido);
               cout<<"Ingrese edad: ";
               getline(cin,edad);
               cout<<"Ingrese direccion: ";
               getline(cin,direccion);
               cout<<"Ingresa telefono? S/N: ";
               string opc;
               getline(cin,opc);
               if (opc == "s" || opc == "S"){
                       int op;
                       cout<<"1>Fijo y movil\n2>Fijo\n3>Movil"<<endl;
                       cin>>op;
                       switch(op){
                                  case 1: cout<<"Ingrese los 2 numeros: ";
                                          cin>>fijo;
                                          cin>>movil;
                                          pero[i]=Persona(nombreApellido, edad, direccion, fijo, movil);
                                       break;
                                  case 2: cout<<"Ingrese el fijo: ";
                                          cin>>fijo;
                                          pero[i]=Persona(nombreApellido, edad, direccion, fijo);
                                       break;
                                  case 3: cout<<"Ingrese el movil: ";
                                          cin>>movil;
                                          pero[i]=Persona(nombreApellido, edad, direccion, movil);
                                       break;
                       }
               }
               else{
                    pero[i]=Persona(nombreApellido, edad, direccion);
               }
           }

           for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
           {
               if (pero[i].da.tele.fijo== "NULL" && pero[i].da.tele.movil == "NULL"){
                                       cout<<pero[i].nombreApellido<<"\t"<<pero[i].edad<<"\t"<<pero[i].direccion<<endl;
               }
               else{
                    if (pero[i].da.tele.fijo == "NULL"){
                          cout<<pero[i].nombreApellido<<"\t"<<pero[i].edad<<"\t"<<pero[i].direccion<<"\t"<<pero[i].da.tele.movil<<endl;                   
                    }
                    else{
                         if (pero[i].da.tele.movil == "NULL"){
                                  cout<<pero[i].nombreApellido<<"\t"<<pero[i].edad<<"\t"<<pero[i].direccion<<"\t"<<pero[i].da.tele.fijo<<endl;                 
                         }
                         else{
                              cout<<pero[i].nombreApellido<<"\t"<<pero[i].edad<<"\t"<<pero[i].direccion<<"\t"<<pero[i].da.tele.fijo<<"\t"<<pero[i].da.tele.movil<<endl;
                         }
                    }
               }
           }
      }

      Dato da;
};
```

Comment: Por favor, envíanos el código que ejecutas así sabemos en que línea tenes el problema.

Answer (score 7):

Si yo escribo:

```
Persona p("1","2","3","4");
```

¿A que constructor estoy llamando? Porque si te fijas hay dos opciones:

```
Persona (string nombreApellido, string edad, string direccion, string fijo);

Persona (string nombreApellido, string edad, string direccion, string movil);
```

Yo no sabría decirlo y el compilador tampoco... de ahí el error.

La solución más sencilla es eliminar la ambigüedad y eso solo se puede conseguir bien eliminando uno de los dos constructores bien modificando uno de ellos para que las firmas sean diferentes. Quizás sería viable pasar `numero` a entero (digo *quizás* porque ignoro si es un requisito que sea de tipo `string`).

Otra posible solución sería preparar el código para que a cada tipo de dato le corresponda una clase diferente... Algo así como una envoltura tonta que evite estas colisiones:

```
class NumeroFijo
{
  std::string valor;

public:

  NumeroFijo()
  {}

  explicit NumeroFijo(std::string const& valor)
    : valor(valor)
  {}

  // Cast implícito
  operator std::string() const
  { return valor; }

  NumeroFijo& operator=(std::string const& cad)
  {
    valor = cad;
    return *this;
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, NumeroFijo const& numero);

  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, NumeroFijo& numero);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, NumeroFijo const& numero)
{ return out << numero.valor; }

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, NumeroFijo& numero)
{ return in >> numero.valor; }


Persona (string nombreApellido, string edad, string direccion, NumeroFijo fijo);
```

Piensa que esta envoltura se podría complicar algo más incorporando, por ejemplo, una implementación de los operadores de comparación para permitir ordenaciones.

¿Te preguntas cómo se usaría esta clase? un pequeño ejemplo:

```
void func1(string)
{ std::cout << "func1(string)\n"; }

void func1(NumeroFijo)
{ std::cout << "func1(NumeroFijo)\n"; }

void func2(NumeroFijo)
{ std::cout << "func1(NumeroFijo)\n"; }

int main()
{
  NumeroFijo test;

  std::cout << "Test1: compatibilidad con entradas / salidas\n";
  std::cout << "Introduce un nombre:";
  std::cin >> test;
  std::cout << test;

  std::cout << "\n\nTest2: uso en funciones\n";
  func1(test);
  func1("test");
  //func2("una cadena"); <-- ERROR. No compila

  std::cout << "\n\nTest3: asignaciones\n";
  test = "una prueba"; // operador de asignación
  NumeroFijo test2("otra prueba"); // construcción de nuevos objetos
  std::cout << test << '\n' << test2;
}
```

En cuanto a temas de rendimiento, los compiladores de hoy en día son muy listos y el overhead que puede llegar a meter este uso lo normal es que tienda a 0 en modo release.

Por cierto, la librería [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/), dispone de una macro llamada [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) que escribe una clase algo más completa que esta escribiendo únicamente una línea.

Y volviendo a tu problema, lo mismo te está sucediendo aquí:

```
Telefono(string fijo);

Telefono (string movil);
```

Y aquí:

```
Dato(string fijo);

Dato (string movil);
```